# MariaDB Access denied in locally connection

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have created a user in MaraiDB:

`CREATE USER 'tuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';`

I can connect to the MariaDB instance remotely (from other machines), But the Access Denied error is raised when I am going to connect to the instance from local server.

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for ...
**

I have tested by set -h parameter to the server name, localhost and 127.0.0.1, but the error is raised yet.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'tuser'@'server_maria' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'tuser'@'192.168.1.50' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'tuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'tuser'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

MriaDB Version is:
10.11.6-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolve by the following link:

[MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-)
for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=2